# haskell : could anyone explain the below algebric data type

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

could anyone explain the below algebric data type

```
data LOS = Cons Student LOS | Empty deriving (Show)
```

and

```
type Name = String



data Student = Student           
  { firstName :: Name
  , lastName :: Name
  } deriving (Eq, Show)
```

I find it confusing the construction of the LOS data type

Comment: it's exactly what a list (of `Student`s) is - `Cons` is `:` and `Empty` is `[]`

Comment: The recursive definition of `LOS` resembles a (linked) list. Values of that type are either the empty list or a node (called `Cons`) containing some payload and the rest of the list.

Comment: A good introduction to recursive data types: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_data_type

Comment: your `LOS` is literally `List Of Students`..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LOS` is defining a list of students. You either have an empty list (`Empty`) or `Cons`, which holds both a value or the rest of the list.

You can have a list with an element (`Cons s1 Empty`), a list with two elements (`Cons s1 (Cons s2 Empty)`) and so on.